# Cypress Typescript: how to store a variable that can be used in the afterEach teardown?

Tags: typescript, cypress, teardown

I have test cases that store data in a variable at the start for it to be used throughout a test. It works fine during the test and can be called up until the very last step of the test before the teardown, but when I try to use it in the `@afterEach` teardown that runs at the end of every test to execute any global clean up commands, the variable shows as empty and has nothing stored in it anymore. It seems the variable gets reset unexpectedly.

The reason I want to run it in the teardown is to ensure that stored data is accessed even if the test case fails before it completes to the very end (thus ensuring the data gets collected in the teardown). How can I get a variable to remain stored properly into the teardown of a Cypress test?

I have tried using a static variable in a class, but that doesn't seem to work.

During each test case, a method stores the data of a user and locks it in a session so it can't be used by other tests running in parallel until it is released from the session.

```
class myUser {
  static user;

  public setUser(params: object): void {
    myUser.user = setAndLockUser(params);
  }

  public releaseLockedUser(): void {
    if (myUser.user == undefined) return;
    releaseTheUserLock(myUser.user);
  }
}
```

At the end of the test case, I want to ensure the session of the user is removed so the user is no longer locked in a session and can be available for test cases yet to run. So we add `releaseUser` to the `afterEach` method:

```
afterEach(() => {
  myUser.releaseLockedUser();
});
```

This is where the issue of the stored variable not being recognized is encountered. Throughout the test, the user variable is stored successfully, but during the afterEach teardown the variable is empty and the session cannot be cleared correctly.

Comment: Provide some code as an example of what you're trying to achieve and/or what you have already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store your values in a Cypress environment variable and reset the state in the `afterEach()`. *Please keep reading after this code example*.

```js
class myUser {
  public setUser(params: object): void {
    Cypress.env('user', setAndLockUser(params);
  }

  public releaseLockedUser(): void {
    if (Cypress.env('user') {
      releaseTheUserLock(Cypress.env('user'));
    }
  }
}
...
afterEach(() => {
  /**
   * the `.then()` may not be necessary or feasible, but using to show 
   * how you should be careful to clear the environment variable after
   * you're sure that you've released your locked user.
   */
  myUser.releaseLockedUser().then(() => {
    Cypress.env('user', undefined);
  });
});
```

While the article Fody references is directly from Cypress, and does make some compelling points, I still believe there is a place for planned uses of `after` and `afterEach`. Is it better to use `before` or `beforeEach` when you can? Absolutely. But if your case truly calls for resetting state after test runs, then you should feel empowered to use it. *With all of that said*, in your use case, I'm not sure you need to use an `afterEach()`. Instead, you could pass in your user as an environment variable in the test, and check if the user is locked in your `beforeEach()`.

```js
describe('some tests', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // The below function should take `Cypress.env('user')` and check if the user is locked
    // If the user is locked, release the lock.
    releaseTheUserLock();
  });

  it('some test', { env: { user: 'foo' } }, () => {
    // some test that uses the user.
    // user can be reference by `Cypress.env('user')`
  })
});
...
// Additionally, I like to make functions that simplify passing in that environment variable --
const user = (user: string) => {
  return { env: { user } };
});
// used in the following way
it('some test', user('foo'), () => {});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this solution works great! It's a bit concerning that Cypress would limit how to structure my own test architecture. Using the environment variable is a good solution, but it does seem like a workaround that shouldn't really be necessary. For my purpose where the next test case may be using an entirely different user than the previous test case, it makes sense to teardown the user entirely within the same test case it was used. Though I haven't configured parallel test running yet to see how it runs there, but for now this works well.

Comment: My own opinion on the matter is they push very hard to not use `after`/`afterEach` because Cypress tests don't run those if the test fails or is interrupted, which can put you in a weird state. (I think this is a mocha limitation, but point still stands). And if you're aware of that limitation, you can more easily construct your `after`/`afterEach` blocks to work within that.

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Using after or afterEach hooks](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Using-after-or-afterEach-hooks)

> Anti-Pattern: Using after or afterEach hooks to clean up state.

The same would apply for any use of state ***if the test case fails before it completes***

Why don't you provide an explicit example of what you want to do, maybe can provide an alternative.

---

Following the guidelines given by Cypress, you would perform `releaseLockedUser()` in a `beforeEach()` rather in an `afterEach()` which might not be called if the test fails.

That way each test sees a clean static user value.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have shared some additional information to my question, hopefully that will better explain things.

Comment: The problem with this is that calling releaseLockedUser() in the beforeEach would also not clear the proper user. We don't want to clear every locked session, just the one that is being used by the test case using a specific user. This is why afterEach makes much more sense.

Comment: Sorry, no it doesn't really make sense. Probably you haven't shared enough details.

Comment: If think it through, whatever you want to do in an `afterEach()` can be done in a `beforeEach()`,  because a `beforeEach()` for test #2 always follows the `afterEach()` for test #1.

Comment: In this case `beforeEach` won't work, because I want to unlock a stored user from a 3rd party system at the end of a test case. I'm new to Cypress and will eventually run parallel tests the same way as Selenium, thus a user locking system: to ensure test accounts aren't used at the same time that may cause interference between them (changing settings, etc). However these details are getting away from the issue. The last thing to do is pass in the stored user variable in the teardown to ensure the correct user unlocks at the end, but the variable seems to clear before the teardown is reached.